# Which game is this: you are in the gargoyle garden

Tags: game-identification

What is the text adventure being played in this photograph?

[image: old computer with text adventure]?

The computer is a HP 2647A Graphics Terminal, and the text visible on screen is:

```
 of the road is a 500 foot sheer cliff,over looking the sea shore. The
 road ends here but the wall continues west into the dense forest.

>ENTER GATE

 You are in the gargoyle garden.

 There is a way to go north

>GO DOWN PATH

 My input vocabulary doesn't include the word PATH

>LOOK

 You are in the gargoyle garden.

 There is a way to go west

 High hedges block the view around you but you can see some of the
 gargoyles along the roof of the mansion. There are paths going in several
 directions.

>_
```

Comment: What is the source of that picture?

Comment: Having the text on the question was actually likely very helpful....

Comment: @AshleyNunn I agree! The source is http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:HP_2647A_terminal.jpg

Comment: I made the picture linkified, so I thought it was redundant.  It's pretty easy to read on the full sized picture.

Comment: Since the picture was apparently taken from the Vintage Computer Festival East 2012, you might be in luck if you [got in touch with them.](http://www.vintage.org/contact.php) :)

Comment: This actually looks better than playing Elvira: Mistress of the dark.

Comment: @Frank: Having the text *as text* allows search engines to index it (so other people searching for a string of this scene can find this question) and [screen reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader) users to participate (text adventures are one of the game types that can be played by blind users).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's [Mystery Mansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_Mansion_%28video_game%29) given the mainframe in question and the [time frame](http://www.lysator.liu.se/adventure/Mainframe_adventures.html). The reference to mansion in the bottom paragraph gives it away. Additionally this is confirmed by going through the game's [source code](http://www.ifarchive.org/if-archive/games/pc/mansion-19.2.tar.gz), specifically the FORTRAN .f file:

```
 58 FORMAT(/" HIGH HEDGES BLOCK THE VIEW AROUND YOU BUT YOU CAN SEE ",
     1"SOME OF THE"/" GARGOYLES ALONG THE ROOF OF THE MANSION. THERE ",
     2"ARE PATHS GOING IN SEVERAL"/" DIRECTIONS.")
```

The game was remade for various systems including [DOS](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~sorem002/mm.html) and [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mystery.mansion.adventure&hl=en).

Comment: Great catch! I loved that game. And Enchanted Castle. And African Adventure.